# How to add or subtract two enum values in swift

Tags: enums, swift3

So I have this `enum` that defines different view positions on a View controller when a side bar menu is presented. I need to add, subtract, multiply, or divide the different values based on different situations. How exactly do I form a method to allow me to use `-`, `+`, `*`, or `/` operators on the values in the `enum`. I can find plenty examples that use the compare operator `==`. Although I haven't been able to find any that use `>=`. Which I also need to be able to do.

Here is the `enum`

```
enum FrontViewPosition: Int {
    case None
    case LeftSideMostRemoved
    case LeftSideMost
    case LeftSide
    case Left
    case Right
    case RightMost
    case RightMostRemoved
}
```

Now I'm trying to use these operators in functions like so.

```
func getAdjustedFrontViewPosition(_ frontViewPosition: FrontViewPosition, forSymetry symetry: Int) {
    var frontViewPosition = frontViewPosition
    if symetry < 0 {
        frontViewPosition = .Left + symetry * (frontViewPosition - .Left)
    }
}
```

Also in another function like so.

```
func rightRevealToggle(animated: Bool) {
    var toggledFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPosition = .Left
    if self.frontViewPosition >= .Left {
        toggledFrontViewPosition = .LeftSide
    }
    self.setFrontViewPosition(toggledFrontViewPosition, animated: animated)
}
```

I know that i need to directly create the functions to allow me to use these operators. I just don't understand how to go about doing it. A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use an `Int` raw value and then perform your comparisons on the raw value, but I suspect you are just trying to do the wrong thing here.

Comment: What does subtracting left mean? o.0'

Comment: FYI - The cases of your enum and their uses in your code don't match. Example: `Left` vs. `.left`.

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. I don't think you really mean an enum here. This really looks like you just want constants.

Comment: Or possibly a struct that includes the required operation functions.

Comment: @rmaddy I made a typo when making this post i didn't directly copy and paste. I've updated the question.

Comment: @RobNapier - The OP is right *not* to use constants. By using an enum and appropriate operators they get strong typing, no mixing integers and `FrontViewPosition` values accidentally.

Comment: @CRD You're correct given the unstated assumption here that `symetry` should actually of type `PositionDistance` rather than `Int` and that this algebra forms a ring. It's unclear from the question that there are no points between `Left` and `Right` or that `succ(.Left)` is `.Right`. The inclusion of `*` and `/` is very confusing in this algebra, and I'm not clear how your solution addresses those (but the OP doesn't seem to have really wanted them).

Comment: Suggesting that `FrontViewPosition + Int` should be a valid operation does, though, raise exactly the concern you had about mixing integers and `FrontViewPosition` values accidentally. (`.LeftSideMost + 3 == .Right` is not really a very obvious result). I'm not sure that's really a good idea. It's unclear what this type really represents, though.

Comment: @RobNapier - Of course there are questions, but we can reasonably infer many of the answers. We know all the values in the set (they are enumerated), they are ordered (so succ, pred, comp), `+` is being used as repeated succ/predi (so +/-: type x int -> type), `-` is being used to determine no. of pred/succ (-: type x type -> int), and no. of succ/prep applications is a count (so int rather than custom). What to do about under/overflow is undefined so we pick one (wrap rather than clamp or error) stating that we did. Surely an under-specified algebra with an enum  is better than one with ints?

Comment: I had read this question (since it included things like multiplication and division) as having `.Left` be a tab stop, such that there are points between `.Left` and `.Right`. So for example, if one wants to say "10 points to the right of `.Left`". In that case, typed constants are a better model. I'm still not clear what `*` and `/` are supposed to be in this system.

Comment: Making this algebra a ring also does not allow `>` to be really obviously defined (which was part of the question, but apparently not really required). `.RightMostRemoved + 1` is less than `.RightMostRemoved`. I'd have to think if this really breaks anything about `>`, but it is surprising. (I think I'm using "ring" incorrectly here…I can't remember the right word for modulo arithmetic)

Comment: (Yeah, this does break `>`. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211454/in-mod3-is-3-greater-than-or-less-than-1#1211463)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are trying to define has a similar algebra to pointers in that you can add an offset to a pointer to get a pointer and subtract two pointers to get a difference. Define these two operators on your enum and your other functions will work.

Any operators over your type should produce results in your type. There are different ways to achieve this, depending on your requirements. Here we shall treat your type as a wrap-around ("modulo") one - add 1 to the last literal and you get the first. To do this we use raw values from `0` to `n` for your types literals and use modulo arithmetic.

First we need a modulo operator which always returns a +ve result, the Swift `%` can return a -ve one which is not what is required for modulo arithmetic.

```
infix operator %% : MultiplicationPrecedence
func %%(_ a: Int, _ n: Int) -> Int
{
   precondition(n > 0, "modulus must be positive")
   let r = a % n
   return r >= 0 ? r : r + n
}
```

Now your enum assigning suitable raw values:

```
enum FrontViewPosition: Int
{
   case None = 0
   case LeftSideMostRemoved = 1
   case LeftSideMost = 2
   case LeftSide = 3
   case Left = 4
   case Right = 5
   case RightMost = 6
   case RightMostRemoved = 7
```

Now we define the appropriate operators.

For addition we can add an integer to a `FrontViewPosition` and get a `FrontViewPosition` back. To do this we convert to raw values, add, and then reduce modulo `8` to wrap-around. Note the need for a `!` to return a non-optional `FrontViewPosition` - this will always succeed due to the modulo math:

```
   static func +(_ x : FrontViewPosition, _ y : Int) -> FrontViewPosition
   {
      return FrontViewPosition(rawValue: (x.rawValue + y) %% 8)!
   }
```

For subtraction we return the integer difference between two `FrontViewPosition` values:

```
   static func -(_ x : FrontViewPosition, _ y : FrontViewPosition) -> Int
   {
      return x.rawValue - y.rawValue
   }

}
```

You can define further operators as needed, say a subtraction operator which takes a `FrontViewPosition` and an `Int` and returns a `FrontViewPosition`.

HTH

Comment: This is an even better example. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enum could have function~

```
enum Tst:Int {
    case A = 10
    case B = 20
    case C = 30
    static func + (t1:Tst,t2:Tst) -> Tst {
        return Tst.init(rawValue: t1.rawValue+t2.rawValue)! //here could be wrong!
    }
}

var a = Tst.A
var b = Tst.B
var c = a+b
```